# I am getting Rlang errors in R and I am unable to do any of my coding or import data

Tags: r, rlang

I cannot run code or import any data without receiving these warnings. I have no clue why this is happening I have not seen this. [image]

here is another error when I am trying to update the package
[image]

I have tried restarting

Comment: I think you just need to remove the rlang package and then reinstall it.

Comment: Run `.libPaths()` in R and copy the path. Close R and go to that path. Delete the rlang folder. Then open R and use install.packages ("rlang")

Answer (score 1):

Some of the code you're trying to run uses the [rlang package](https://rlang.r-lib.org/), which is commonly used by other packages to do things like formatting error messages. One of the packages you are using needs a recent version of the rlang package, but the version on your computer is an older version. You can solve this by updating the version of the rlang package on your computer.

1. Restart R (in RStudio, click `Session` then `Restart R`).
2. In the R console, run `update.packages()`. Lots of packages will be updated, so this might be a good time to grab a beverage.
3. If you get the message shown in your second screen shot ("One or more of the packages …"), click "No", since you have already re-started R.

You should now find your code works as expected.